# Is this method of charging a lead acid battery safe, or even good!

Tags: voltage-regulator, lead-acid

so I need to know if my method/circuit of charging a **6V Lead Acid Battery** is safe or even workable! so this is the circuit and battery info!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWQuA7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- 6V/2Ah Lead Acid Battery
- Model - SD620
- Type - VALVE Regulated
- Voltage Charge Type - Constant - "Also it writes Constay, I think
  it's a typo!"
- Cycle Use - 7.25V - 7.45V
- Standby Use - 6.8V- 6.9V
- Initial Current - Less Than 1.2A

Comment: It is suboptimal due to power loss in regulator with 1.2A and about 4W when discharged to 5.75V, then exceeds standby voltage. or 6.9V. Safe? probably ? reliable? too hot for regulator so it will cut in and out. reduce battery life?, yes somewhat, efficient? no, slow? yes.. good? not really... you want an SLA charger or a 6V 6W light bulb and watch the voltage never exceeds 7.4 and disconnect immediately

Comment: related: [BU-403: Charging Lead Acid](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_the_lead_acid_battery) on Battery University

Comment: the thing is that the regulator is not even hot, I got a small heatsink on it and it's cold!

Comment: Check the input voltage on the 7807. They generally need a few volts more on the input pin than on the output. The datasheet will give you details on that. Don't omit the recommended capacitors or the device may oscillate.

Comment: hah, my circuit got no capacitors, why would it need it, this ain't an electronic device, its a battery?

Comment: Also, the output voltage on the ac-dc power adapter is 14.50v but on the sticker, it writes 9v. and output of the 7807 is 7v

Comment: whats also to note is that the power adapter is getting warm!

Comment: i could switch to another power adapter I got and it's a 12V 1A, i think it would be better?

Comment: "output voltage on the ac-dc power adapter is 14.50v but on the sticker, it writes 9v"- that's normal. Voltage will drop close to 9V at rated load.

Comment: What is the Amp rating of your power adapter?

Comment: It won't hurt the battery as long as you don't leave it there indefinitely. If the regulator is cold to the touch, it is probably not charging, either because the battery is full, or because something is broken or wired wrong. Some power adapters are always warm when plugged in. May not indicate any problem. I would expect the regulator to get hot at some point during the full charge cycle.

Comment: I know that the regulator ait broke because it lowers voltage and the battery does get charged.

Comment: btw can I charge a lead acid battery with 1Amp?